# Where is the OneNote offline-copy stored on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onenote

As the title says, where is t it stored?
I can't find the offline copy of my notes, neither on the internal nor the external memory.
Are they in a hidden directory, I can't see on Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score -2):

Try looking here: `OneDrive / Documents`

Comment: That's not where the **offline** copy lies... and furthermore that directory does not exist on Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: I check on my Lumia 830 with Windows 10 mobile before answering. That's the default path for OneNote notebooks: I also tried to create a new notebook from the OneNote app and it's saved there. What do you mean with "offline copy"? When I edit my notebook the new version is saved in the path I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Where are you seeing this path? File Explorer? Or are you talking about the OneDrive app?

Comment: OneDrive app. I don't think you can access it from the File app.

Comment: yes you can always see it in OneDrive\Documents...but thats not where it is on the file system